# Weird macro behavior for type inference

Tags: macros, rust

I'm trying to understand macros & utilizing a simple macro to create a hashmap similar to `vec!`. For some reason if I convert a `String` into an `&str` inside the macro it doesn't seem to work.

```
macro_rules! hashmap {
    ($( $key: expr => $val: expr ),*) => {{
         let mut map = ::std::collections::HashMap::new();
         $( map.insert($key.clone(), $val.clone()); )*
         map
    }}
}

fn works(){
    let value1 = 5;
    let value1str: &str = &value1.to_string();
    let h = hashmap!["key0"   => "value0"
                     , "key1" => value1str];
    println!("{:?}", h);
}

// fn does_not_work(){
//     let value1 = 5;
//     let h = hashmap!["key0"   => "value0"
//                      , "key1" => &value1.to_string()];
//     println!("{:?}", h);
// }

fn main(){
    works();
    //does_not_work();
}
```

[Example on playpen](http://is.gd/ny2nvC)

Comment: *if I convert a `String` into an `&str` inside the macro* — have you tried it outside of a macro? Do you get any error messages? Have you tried searching for those error messages? Saying something is "weird" or that it "doesn't work" is the least useful kind of request for help.

Comment: I did try it outside. It is described **exactly** in the `works()` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the effective body of your `works()` function:

```
fn works(){
    let value1 = 5;
    let value1str: &str = &value1.to_string();
    let h = {
        let mut map = HashMap::new();
        map.insert("key0".clone(), "value0".clone());
        map.insert("key1".clone(), value1str.clone());
        map
    };
    println!("{:?}", h);
}
```

And this one of `does_not_work()`:

```
fn does_not_work(){
    let value1 = 5;
    let h = {
        let mut map = HashMap::new();
        map.insert("key0".clone(), "value0".clone());
        map.insert("key1".clone(), (&value1.to_string()).clone());
        map
    };
    println!("{:?}", h);
}
```

When `clone()` is called on an `&str`, it is just a simple byte-wise copy of a fat pointer (two pointer-sized numbers): shared references are always `Copy`; the cloned reference also has the same lifetime as the original one, naturally. This is okay in `works()` because three of string slices used there point to static memory as they are string literals, and the fourth one points to a temporary local variable which lives until the end of the function:

```
let value1str: &str = &value1.to_string();
// is in fact equivalent to
let temporary = value1.to_string();
let value1str: &str = &temporary;
```

Because this `temporary` lives longer than the hash map, a reference to it can be stored inside this hash map: the map gets destroyed first and never gets a chance to hold a dangling reference.

In the second case, however, `clone()` is called on a value of type `&String`, because `&s` if `s: String` will give you `&str` only if the compiler knows that `&str` should be the target type, and this is not the case because `&value1.to_string()` is passed to `clone()` afterwards. When `clone()` is called on `&String`, it naturally delegates to `impl Clone for String` which just makes another owned copy of a string, giving you `String`. This in turn gives you a type mismatch error:

```
<anon>:20:34: 4:50 error: mismatched types:
 expected `&str`,
    found `collections::string::String`
(expected &-ptr,
    found struct `collections::string::String`) [E0308]
```

There is a way to work around it - you can ask `&str` out of a `&String` directly, e.g. with explicit reborrowing:

```
&*value1.to_string()
```

However, another problem will now arise. Whatever temporary value `value1.to_string()` returns is only valid during the expression inside which it is used:

```
map.insert("key1".clone(), (&*value1.to_string()).clone());
// is roughly equivalent to
{
    let temporary = value1.to_string();
    map.insert("key1".clone(), (&*temporary).clone());
}  // these braces are important!
```

You can see that `temporary` will be immediately destroyed when the call to `insert()` completes, and the inserted reference would become dangling. Rust prevents that with a compiler error.

Comment: Thank you for the clear, concise & constructive explanation!